# Working with ctypes return values

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, ctypes

I am looking into calling C++ code from Python. I just learned about ctypes and have seen a few examples on the web. I am trying to call a C++ function that looks like the following:

```c
get_data(re * data_record, char * string)
```

Having no clue about c++, I am going to ask some basics. How **should** I be calling such a function from python using ctypes.
I've decided to take a step back because I think I'm missing some fundamentals here.

In fact for any C++ function that takes an argument of type string and returns an integer see some examples

```c
struct db_obj {
    char db_name[50],
    int_32 db_guid,
    char db_path[100];
};

get_database_running_status(db *db_obj,int_8 db_id,int_8 *retvalue);

get_database_running_status_string(db *db_obj,int_8 db_id,char *retvalue);
```

This function will return a status value(retvalue) that I can decode to know the status of the database e.g 10=running fine, 11=stropped, 12=pause, 404=fault, etc.

While get_database_running_status_string will return the string and not just the number

How would I go about calling these? Not sure what that * symbol is all about though I hope it helps.

Maybe once I understand how to correctly call C++ functions from python then my issue may resolve itself.

Comment: How do you call the function? (please include the code - i am interested about the function arguments as well). Have you tried calling it from a c program? Also have you tried simplifying the problem (e.g. call a func with no arg that simply returns an `char*`) and call it from python (`restype` works in that case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting an actual example of working C++ code would help, but I'll just create something similar as a demo.

Here's brief C++ DLL source.  Since `ctypes` wraps C functions, not C++, the functions are declared `extern "C"` to work properly.  I'm doing this on Windows, so `__declspec(dllexport)` is used to mark the functions as exported from the DLL:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct record {
    int x,y;
};

typedef int int_32;
typedef char int_8;

struct db_obj {
    char db_name[50];
    int_32 db_guid;
    char db_path[100];
};

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void get_data_int(record* pRec, int* pResult) {
        *pResult = pRec->x + pRec->y;
    };
    __declspec(dllexport) void get_data_string(record* pRec, char* pResult, size_t size) {
        sprintf_s(pResult,size,"%d + %d = %d\n", pRec->x, pRec->y, pRec->x + pRec->y);
    }
    __declspec(dllexport) void get_database_running_status(db_obj* db, int_8 db_id, int_8 *retvalue) {
        printf("db_name = %s\ndb_guid = %d\ndb_path = %s\ndb_id = %d\n", db->db_name, db->db_guid, db->db_path, db_id);
        *retvalue = 42;
    }
}
```

Here's the `ctypes` wrapper:

```
#!python2
import ctypes as c

class Record(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x',c.c_int),('y',c.c_int)]

class db_obj(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('db_name',c.c_char * 50),
                ('db_guid',c.c_int),
                ('db_path',c.c_char * 100)]

dll = c.CDLL('x')

get_data_int = dll.get_data_int
get_data_int.argtypes = [c.POINTER(Record), c.POINTER(c.c_int)]
get_data_int.restype = None

get_data_string = dll.get_data_string
get_data_string.argtypes = [c.POINTER(Record), c.POINTER(c.c_char), c.c_size_t]
get_data_string.restype = None

get_database_running_status = dll.get_database_running_status
get_database_running_status.argtypes = [c.POINTER(db_obj), c.c_int8, c.POINTER(c.c_int8)]
get_database_running_status.restype = None

result = c.c_int()
rec = Record(5,7)
get_data_int(c.byref(rec),c.byref(result))
print(result.value)

result = c.create_string_buffer(50)
rec = Record(5,7)
get_data_string(c.byref(rec),result,c.sizeof(result))
print(result.value)

result = c.c_int8()
db = db_obj('database name',1234,'database path')
get_database_running_status(c.byref(db),7,c.byref(result))
print(result.value)
```

Output:

```
12
5 + 7 = 12

db_name = database name
db_guid = 1234
db_path = database path
db_id = 7
42
```

See the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#module-ctypes) documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to add a more realistic code sample, See updated question. I'm still not clear on how to pass a string into the function, I see argtypes c.POINTER(c.c_char), but how to i pass in "hello world" as the input parmeter?

Comment: Also does it mean that when the C function has a * that means the python argtypes must have ctypes.POINTER(appropriate CTYPE)?

Comment: @user595985, for an input string, use `c_char_p` and pass the input string.  For an output string, use `POINTER(c_char)`, allocate the memory to hold the string with `create_string_buffer`, and pass the buffer.  The `*` in the C++ definition indicates a pointer to a value, which is why I used `POINTER`. Note that `c_char_p` for an input string is already a pointer and doesn't need to be wrapped in `POINTER`.  I get the impression you don't know C/C++?  That will make it diffcult to use `ctypes` :)

Comment: Thank you, your last comment and example really did it for me. You're absolutely right I don't know C/C++, First time i've had to interact with C in any meaningful way. Types..who needs them(just kidding). Thank you